# Job fails to read from one ORC file and write a subset to another

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hortonworks-data-platform

Working in the Apache Pig interactive shell in HDP 2.3 for Windows, I've got an existing ORC file in `/path/to/file`. If I load and then save that using:

```
a = LOAD '/path/to/file' USING OrcStorage('');
STORE a INTO '/path/to/second_file' USING OrcStorage('');
```

Then everything works. However, if I try:

```
a = LOAD '/path/to/file' USING OrcStorage('');
b = LIMIT a 10;
STORE b INTO '/path/to/third_file' USING OrcStorage('');
```

Then I get the following error traceback in the logs for the second job (out of two that it schedules):

```
2015-08-25 16:03:42,161 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Error starting MRAppMaster
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/io/orc/OrcNewOutputFormat
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.resolveClassName(PigContext.java:657)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.instantiateFuncFromSpec(PigContext.java:726)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POStore.getStoreFunc(POStore.java:251)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputCommitter.getCommitters(PigOutputCommitter.java:88)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputCommitter.<init>(PigOutputCommitter.java:71)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.getOutputCommitter(PigOutputFormat.java:289)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$1.call(MRAppMaster.java:476)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$1.call(MRAppMaster.java:458)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.callWithJobClassLoader(MRAppMaster.java:1560)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.createOutputCommitter(MRAppMaster.java:458)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.serviceInit(MRAppMaster.java:377)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$4.run(MRAppMaster.java:1518)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(MRAppMaster.java:1515)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1448)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcNewOutputFormat
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I suspect that the classpath for the two jobs is different, causing a ClassNotFound. Is that likely to be the case? If so, how can I fix it? (Bonus question: Why has this happened?)

Answer (score 2):

Check the dependent library for OrcStorage is placed in all nodes.

- The first option only spawn single job
- The second option will spawn multiple jobs which maybe run in different machine
  which doesnt have the dependent library in its classpath.

Comment: Currently I'm only using the one node - is it possible that the second job gets called differently? (ie. without that JAR in the classpath?)

Comment: one more odd thing i found is

`STORE b '/path/to/third_file' USING OrcStorage('');`
instead of 
`STORE b INTO '/path/to/third_file' USING OrcStorage('');`

Comment: Oh, right, that was me making a mistake while taking out the  actual path I'm using with this example. Fixed now.